# Should I use a MVC javascript framwork for this application?

Tags: javascript

I've been asked at work to convert a popular mechanical engineering excel application to a single page web application. It requires no database so my idea is to put everything on the clientside in javascript.

First version is gonna be pretty small but more complexity will be added further along. Canvas graphics is gonna be drawn in realtime as user changes input. So performance is important. My question is: Should I use a MVC framework such as Angular JS? Or is it better to stick with Jquery? If I should use a MVC, which one is best suited for this app?

Everyone at my company uses IE9 so I dont need any support for older browsers.

Comment: The best tool is the one you know better. Always.

Comment: I think the first question should ask is why it needs to be a single page app. Maybe it does, but until you understand the reason you won't be able to make the right choices.

Comment: I totally disagree with you @zerkms. It is often better to get started with a new, but convenient framework, according to your needs, than lose your time using one you know, but who is inconvenient. Working with the same framework ever will not help you in the long term.

Comment: @Flo-Schield-Bobby: when you're learning some new tool - you would never be able write something using those tool best practices. So the solution will likely be messy and badly written. Learning projects should never be published for production --- it's all my personal opinion.

Comment: I respect it, but mine is that if the framework is well-documented, and if you - really - get started, there's no reason to mess or bad write your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular bills itself specifically as a way to build CRUD apps - basically database front ends. The app you're describing doesn't sound like it's doing a ton of that, so Angular would probably be more trouble than it's worth.

jQuery is a helper library - it makes dealing with the DOM easier, but doesn't do a thing to provide overall structure to your application. jQuery is a "necessary but not sufficient" in my book - you're going to want it, but it's not enough on its own.

Personally, I'd lean more towards Backbone, specifically because it's so minimal - it gives you some useful data binding stuff and some hints on how to organize your app, then gets out of your way to let you build the abstraction you want. Based on the fact that you mentioned the original is in Excel, some sort of data binding / change notification system is going to be important. This way you can emulate the spreadsheet's "change a cell and the chart redraws" system that everyone's already used to.

In the end it's hard to say without more detail on the app in question, and what kind of calculations / how often they have to happen are. Figure out what your app architecture should be, find (or build) a library that helps implement that architecture. It might be MVCish, it might not.

Comment: While I completely agree with the above just another suggestion would be knockout.js which has some very nice tutorials and plugins. Again just an additional option over backbone.

Answer (score 2):

Well jQuery will get very messy as complexity increases. Angular JS is an amazing library but there are also a myriad of different ones out there. Depending on the Mechanical Engineering principles you are working with using AJAX may prove to be more perform-ant, due to the lack luster power of some older browsers.

It really depends on the complexity of the calculations, but in terms of dealing with events and managin the structure I would suggest using Jquery as well as Angular on top of it. then make the decision about whether or not to move some functions to the server or not, based on performance.