# Add listeners to label

Tags: jquery

I'm converting an excel appplication to a single web page application. Since I want users to feel familiar I want everything to update in realtime when user changes input, just as in excel. It works great but it starting to be messy since diffrent output labels depend on eachother.

Is there anyway I can add a listner to a label instead of setting a value to the label when user enters input in textboxes?

Comment: you could do this with jQuery but after a while it would get very complex and hard to maintain. I would suggest using something like Knockout.js or Backbone.js possibly AngularJS as well.

Comment: I agree with @Nomad101. jQuery could work but for a small number of changes..otherwise you are lost.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware I should have used a mvc-framework. See my previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268331/should-i-use-a-mvc-javascript-framwork-for-this-application . This is just a "proof of concept". It's not that many controls so I can hopefully pull it off with jquery. If I'll get an order to make the full version I'm gonna rewrite and learn a mvc-framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments...I'm not encouraging you to do it this way but if you have a small amount of elements to change then [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is function that you could use to achieve what you need.

You can see a working example on this site:
[jQuery change() example](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok to expand on my comment to the original question. While, what you ask is most definitely possibly with jQuery. Something as complex as a spreadsheet would require extensive jQuery referencing and hookup code which overtime would become almost unsustainable if not completely.

However to answer your question you would want to most likely bind to the `onChange` event of the input in question. This would allow you to get almost instant updates throughout your ui. Something like this could easily work to do this:

`$("#InputInQuestion").on("change", function(e) { //Do Something } );`

This approach will eventually lead to some very hard to read and hard to maintain code as you progress through this kind of app. Just imagine writing that kind of function for every single event on a spread sheet style app and you may get why you should probably stay away from this method.

There are a multitude of viable frameworks that make what you ask almost trivial, key word being almost.

Knockout.js for instance comes with a mapping plugin that would allow you to dynamically map server data to objects in your html. All of these objects would be dynamically set throughout the lifetime of the app. What I mean is that when ever a value in one of your cells changes you would get the desired effect of having the rest of the ui change to reflect this as well, without having to write massive amounts of hookup coding.

Their site http://knockoutjs.com/ has some awesome tutorials on how to get started.

AngularJS is also an amazing utility for making robust and responsive UI's which you can take a look at here: http://angularjs.org/

Backbone.js is very similar to the above which can be found here: http://backbonejs.org/